# Flutter 3.19 and Firestore issue

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
error C2440: '': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'cloud_firestore_windows::AggregateQueryResponse'. error C2512: 'flutter::CustomEncodableValue': no appropriate default constructor available

I need help with a firestore issue with Flutter 3.19.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your configuration data, code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) and [Formatting text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code)

Comment: Please see this : someone reported yesterday on github : https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/12359

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.